# Error on calling initialize after deploying upgradable contract

Tags: contract-deployment

I have deployed my contract to mainnet,All thing was fine but after I tried to call initialize method I got error and I think proxies not initiated

How can I do now?
I lost some Ether and nothing worth that

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;


import '@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/Initializable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/presets/ERC20PresetMinterPauser.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';
contract Token is Initializable, ERC20PresetMinterPauserUpgradeSafe   {
  function initialize() public initializer {
    ERC20PresetMinterPauserUpgradeSafe.initialize("Cryptomind", "CR");
      _setupDecimals(8);
  }


}

? Pick a network mainnet
? Pick a contract to deploy Token 
√ Contract Token deployed
All implementations have been deployed
? Call a function to initialize the instance after creating it? Yes
? Select which function * initialize()
**× Setting everything up to create contract instances
insufficient funds for gas * price + value**

oz call
? Pick a network mainnet
A contract address must be specified.
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but there is no proxy here.

Comment: You need to deploy a factory, then link your contract (library) to this factory and then you can issue proxies. Check EIP 1167, may I ask why you need a proxy here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I found my answer [here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/cant-initialize-upgradeable-contract/3840/2)